# Delete rows with duplicates on two fields

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-delete, duplicate-data

I need to delete duplicated values of this table:

```
+----+-------+-------------+---------+
| id | name  | description | surname |
+----+-------+-------------+---------+
| 1  | Peter | Member      | Hitsh   |
| 2  | James | Member      | Tach    |
| 3  | Mary  | Member      | Popims  |
| 4  | Peter | Member      | Hitsh   |
+----+-------+-------------+---------+
```

I would want to remove all the duplicated values with the same `name` and `surname`.

Comment: So you mean to *keep* 1 row for every set of duplicates? Which one?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the row with the smallest `id` for every set of duplicates on `(name, surname)`:

```
DELETE FROM tbl
USING (
   SELECT id, row_number OVER (PARTITION BY name, surname ORDER BY id) As rn
   FROM   tbl
   ) del
WHERE  tbl.id = del.id
AND    del.rn > 1;
```

Assuming `id` to be unique.

Very similar question today:
[Delete all rows but one with the greatest value per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210878/deleting-rows-in-postgres-using-aggregates-and-subquery-aliases/22211439#22211439)